# Wrong results when grouping by trunc(timestamp)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by

I have an input like:

```
01.03.16 15:48:45.772000000
01.03.16 15:48:49.924000000
01.03.16 21:31:08.320000000
01.03.16 21:56:05.201000000
02.03.16 00:11:10.552000000
02.03.16 00:11:11.652000000
02.03.16 01:31:14.359000000
02.03.16 21:41:11.059000000
03.03.16 00:11:06.850000000
03.03.16 11:05:20.343000000
03.03.16 16:07:07.148000000
04.03.16 18:15:14.460000000
04.03.16 18:55:39.206000000
05.03.16 00:15:21.457000000
05.03.16 00:20:14.908000000
05.03.16 00:50:15.641000000
07.03.16 08:45:19.526000000
07.03.16 21:30:20.562000000
07.03.16 21:45:20.402000000
08.03.16 00:11:12.163000000
08.03.16 14:37:46.607000000
08.03.16 23:16:22.713000000
08.03.16 23:16:22.715000000
```

Now, the idea is to group by date and count rows with time before and after 6.30 p.m. . result should be like:

```
date        before  after
01.03.16    2   2   
02.03.16    3   1   
03.03.16    3   0   
04.03.16    0   2
05.03.16    3   0
07.03.16    1   2
08.03.16    2   2
```

If I group by `trunc(mytimestamp)` and make a `case` in the `select` statement using `mytimestamp` I'm not getting the right result.

My actual query is:

```
select trunc(tscreate),
  to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy')
    + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute as referenz_time,
  sum(case when ( tscreate < to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy')
    + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute) then 1 else 0 end) as beforeTS,
  sum(case when ( tscreate >= to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy')
    + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute) then 0 else 1 end) as afterTS
from customer
where app = 'abc'
and tscreate >= to_date('01.03.2016','dd.MM.yyyy')
group by trunc(tscreate) order by trunc(tscreate)
```

The value for `beforTS` seems to be computed correctly, but `afterTS` is always the same as `beforeTS`, and this is not possible.

Comment: If you need to do you `CASE` on the truncated value, simply use `trun`c in the `CASE`; if you need to do `CASE` on the entire value, what result do you expect? how could you handle two rows with the same truncated value but different values returned from the `CASE`?

Comment: my query loks like: 

 select trunc(tscreate), to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy') + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute as referenz_time,
  sum(case when ( tscreate < to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy') + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute) then 1 else 0 end) as beforeTS,
  sum(case when ( tscreate >= to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy') + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute) then 0 else 1 end) as afterTS
from customer
where app = 'abc' and  tscreate >= to_date('01.03.2016','dd.MM.yyyy')
group by trunc(tscreate)
order by trunc(tscreate)

Comment: Please add that code to the question, not as a comment; and include the result you get from that. Your query doesn't error, but doesn't get the expected result, right? Although it does if you just change the `then 0 else 1` to `then 1 else 0` - you're case condition is reversed so you don't want to reverse that logic too, they cancel each other out. (Your question also says 6:30 but the code says 5:30). So... I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: it's working now. when i copied case for beforeTS i forgot to Change part "then 1 else 0" :) thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you posted as a comment almost works - it doesn't error but doesn't get the result you said you wanted. In the second `case` expression you've change `<` to `>=1` but you've changed `then 0 else 1` to `then 1 else 0` *as well* and those two changes cancel each other out - the logic of both ends up the same, and they're both counting time before 17:30.

So just fixing that gets the result you want:

```
select trunc(tscreate),
  to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy')
    + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute as referenz_time,
  sum(case when ( tscreate < to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy')
    + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute) then 1 else 0 end) as beforeTS,
  sum(case when ( tscreate >= to_timestamp(trunc( trunc(tscreate)),'dd.MM.yy')
    + interval '17' hour + interval '30' minute) then 1 else 0 end) as afterTS
from customer
where app = 'abc'
and tscreate >= to_date('01.03.2016','dd.MM.yyyy')
group by trunc(tscreate)
order by trunc(tscreate);

TRUNC(TSCREATE) REFERENZ_TIME                  BEFORETS    AFTERTS
--------------- ---------------------------- ---------- ----------
01-MAR-16       01-MAR-16 17.30.00.000000000          2          2
02-MAR-16       02-MAR-16 17.30.00.000000000          3          1
03-MAR-16       03-MAR-16 17.30.00.000000000          3          0
04-MAR-16       04-MAR-16 17.30.00.000000000          0          2
05-MAR-16       05-MAR-16 17.30.00.000000000          3          0
07-MAR-16       07-MAR-16 17.30.00.000000000          1          2
08-MAR-16       08-MAR-16 17.30.00.000000000          2          2
```

I'd simplify it slightly, but some of this is down to personal taste:

```
select trunc(tscreate),
  cast(trunc(tscreate)
    + interval '17:30' hour to minute as timestamp) as referenz_time,
  count(case when tscreate < cast(trunc(tscreate)
    + interval '17:30' hour to minute as timestamp) then 1 end) as beforeTS,
  count(case when tscreate >= cast(trunc(tscreate)
    + interval '17:30' hour to minute as timestamp) then 1 end) as afterTS
from customer
where app = 'abc'
and tscreate >= timestamp '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
group by trunc(tscreate)
order by trunc(tscreate);
```

which gets the same result. Or if you don't like intervals you can use date arithmetic instead:

```
select trunc(tscreate),
  trunc(tscreate) + 17.5/24 as referenz_time,
  count(case when tscreate < cast(trunc(tscreate) + 17.5/24 as timestamp) then 1 end) as beforeTS,
  count(case when tscreate >= cast(trunc(tscreate) + 17.5/24 as timestamp) then 1 end) as afterTS
from customer
where app = 'abc'
and tscreate >= timestamp '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
group by trunc(tscreate)
order by trunc(tscreate);
```

(You could even do a string comparison of the extracted time, as David Wallace briefly suggested, i.e. `to_char(tscreate, 'HH24:MI') < '17:30'`. But even though that's 'safe' with 24-hour times, I prefer to stick to the original data type.)

I'm not sure you really need `referenz_time` as a timestamp, and either way if this is for display then you should format the dates and timestamps explicitly rather than rely on NLS settings.

Comment: thanks a lot! i spent a few hours wit5h that issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `trunc(mytimestamp)` anywhere:

```
 select to_char(trunc(mytimestamp), 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
 from my_table
 group by trunc(mytimestamp)
```